# OpenGL - GL_LINE_STRIP acts like GL_LINE_LOOP

Tags: c++, opengl

Im using OpenGL 3.3 with GLFW.
The problem is that GL_LINE_STRIP and GL_LINE LOOP give the same result.

Here is the array of 2D coordinates:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = 
    {
     0, 0,
     1, 1,
     1, 2,
     2, 2,
     3, 1,
    };
```

The attribute pointer:

```
// Position attribute 2D
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

And finally:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, sizeof(vertices)/4);
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;

out vec3 ourColor;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    ourColor = color;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 ourColor;

out vec3 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec3(ourColor);
}
```

The Color attrib. is disabled (lines are black and visible)

Any idea?

Comment: If the clear color is black and the line color is black, I can see `LINE_LOOP` and `LINE_STRIP` giving the same result. Also don't blindly assume `sizeof(float) == 4` (I see you're doing it properly in `vertexAttrib` call)

Comment: Also if the behave the same, *how* do they behave exactly? IOW which one seems broken?

Comment: GLfloat is always 4 bytes afaik, GL_LINE_STRIP acts like GL_LINE LOOP

Comment: `GLfloat` is *at least* 4 bytes.

Comment: in my code:sizeof(GLfloat) is 4, and sizeof(vertices) is 40. I allready tried that, same result...

Comment: Well, there you go; you have only 5 *pairs* of floats, so 5 vertices. 40/4 is 10. `sizeof(array) / (sizeof(array[0]) * dimensionality)` would be the correct equation there.

Comment: Strange, when you render triangles if the count parameter is > num. of triangles, it renders ok, I wasnt aware that this is not the case with GL_LINES

Comment: Sounds like undefined behaviour; expect dragons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only **5** pairs of floats, so **5** vertices. Total size of your array is 4 times 10 floats, so 40 bytes.

Your equation for count, 40/4 gives 10. `sizeof(array) / (sizeof(array[0]) * dimensionality)` would be the correct equation there.